# After JPA Reverse Engineer - No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0

Tags: java, maven, jpa, persistence

I am using Spring 3.1 + MVC + JPA/Hibernate in this project. When i roll back to a revision before the reverse engineer the project builds and I can move around the web app just fine. After the reverse engineer i get this error [full stack trace here](http://pastebin.com/rwP7fA4S):

```
    1972 [main] ERROR springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ageGroupCodeDAO': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0
```

Here are the config files.

### src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
      <display-name></display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
      <jsp-config>
        <taglib>
          <taglib-uri>http://gov.mt.dphhs.mona.domain.pojo/AssessmentQuestion</taglib-uri>
          <taglib-location>taglibs/questionTypes.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
      </jsp-config>
      <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
      </listener>
      <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mona-mvc.xml</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/mona-mvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

### src/main/resources/mona-contenxt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="gov.mt.dphhs.mona" />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MONATest3Pu" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"></bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"></bean>

    </beans>
```

### src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mona-mvc.xmll

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- 
        Scans the packages for controller annotations and registers them.
    -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="gov.mt.dphhs.mona" />

    <!-- 
        Registers the DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping and 
        AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter beans that are required for 
        Spring MVC to dispatch requests to @Controllers
    -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>    

    <!-- 
        Maps static resource requests following a particular URL 
        pattern to be served by a ResourceHttpRequestHandler from 
        any of a list of Resource locations
    -->
    <mvc:resources location="/css/" mapping="/css/**"/>
    <mvc:resources location="/js/" mapping="/js/**"/>
    <mvc:resources location="/images/" mapping="/images/**"/>

    <!-- 
        Maps resolvers to the jsp directory and appends suffix jsp 
    -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="order" value="3" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>gov.mt.dphhs</groupId>
  <artifactId>mona-test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name></name>
  <description></description>
  <properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <war.file.name>mona</war.file.name>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>cglib</groupId>
      <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
      <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>catalina</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.35</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.5.23</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>11.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
      <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
      <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
      <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-struts</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>openid4java-nodeps</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.openid4java</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-remoting</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jasig.cas.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>cas-client-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
      <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>antlr</groupId>
      <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
      <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
      <version>3.15.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>${war.file.name}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing declaration of mona-contenxt.xml in web.xml and instead declared mona-mvc.xml twice.

The change can be something like this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:mona-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: sigh..I knew it was something dumb i had missed. Thanks su-!